# What does it mean when a regex is delimited by colons?

Tags: regex, perl

What function do the colons serve in this Perl regex that I found in some production code?

```
if ($r->uri =~ m:/copy/(\d+):) {
    my $ref = $1;
```

The code is parsing a URI and the second line uses the captured group.

Comment: Are you talking about Perl 6 or Perl 5? Perl 5 doesn't have adverbs.

Comment: Pedantically, there are no colons in your regex. The regex is the bit between the colons - `/copy/(\d+)`. The colons are the delimiter for the match operator (`m/.../`) which is here being spelt as `m:..:` to avoid having to escape the `/` characters in the regex.

Comment: *" I know they're used to delimit adverbs"* Do you mean in written English, or are you getting confused with Perl 6? Perl 5 has nothing called *adverbs*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the `m`, any character can act as the delimiter, so the colons are replacing the standard `/`s and lets them become a normal character.

From [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html):

> the // default delimiters for a match can be changed to arbitrary delimiters by putting an 'm' out front

Answer (score 10):

The `m` operator in perl is used to test a string against a regular expression. You typically use it like that:

```
"string" =~ m/regex/
```

If you want, you can change the quoting character (`/` in the above example). So the above example can be equivalently written as any of the following:

```
"string" =~ m(regex)
"string" =~ m[regex]
"string" =~ m{regex}
"string" =~ m|regex|
"string" =~ m:regex:
```

Note that if you use `/`, then you can omit the `m`, as in

```
"string" =~ /regex/
```

Comment: Note that using `|` (or any other metacharacter for that matter) as the delimiter is *not* the best idea ;-)

Comment: Fwiw - the conundrum of using metacharacter as delimiter is only seen when the body of the expression is trying to match it as a literal.The engine expects the escaped metacharacter and the parser expects an escaped delimiter (too). Raw `(?:A|B)\|` delimited `m|(?:A\|B)\||` then `(?:A|B)|` is sent to engine. Or, if delimited `m|(?:A\|B)\\||` then there will be a parsing error because m`|(?:A\|B)\\|`| is only delimited, leaving a trailing `|`. Better to choose a non-metachar, or one that is not a contextual one like `{}{}`